# Roboto and Roboto thin work fine for me but not for others. Only Roboto Regular works for others

Tags: html, css

Here is the problem. So everything works fine for me on my machine, localhost and when the website is uploaded to online host. But I got my friends to go to the site to check if everything is working and the regular Roboto font loads fine but the thin version of it doesn't. I originally just had the import link from google for the font but later added the font face import code that I found on here but that doesn't work too. I even tried adding the font-weight property but it still doesn't work.

I need help my head hurts real bad here's the code enjoy

Top of the css file

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: local('Roboto'), url(fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf) format('ttf');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto thin';
    src: local('Roboto thin'), url(fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf) format('ttf');
}
```

Class for one of the texts that uses the font

```css
.txt2 { /* text */
    font-family: 'Roboto thin';
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Comment: cool username :)

Answer (score 0):

The @font-face is loading a local file, but also, import in my experience doesn't work like how you expect. I'm on mobile so I can't get too detailed but I usually call the fonts url in the html using a tag in the head. This has the added benefit of the browser being able to pull that file in asynchronously, rather than after the css file loads, which will give you a small speed increase.

More than likely this code is actually failing for you too, but your browser has the font in cache and it's safe to use so it does. Or you have robot installed outright.

EDIT: Alright, I'm on a desktop now, and want to clarify some things.

- `@font-face` defines a font and how it can be called. It gives it a name, where the font files are stored, and if it's considered italicized, normal, etc.
- The Google Fonts file you are calling contains that information, it's whole purpose is to define the things you are putting in your @font-face lines.
- As I said, @import is a bit tricky.

  - First and foremost, make sure your @import statement is the very first thing your CSS file contains. If you only have one @import, it should be the first line.
  - Using Google Fonts' other option, the HTML , will work marginally faster. The difference may stop your users from seeing a flicker of the wrong font on their first page load.
- Remove the @font-face rules you have altogether, they are overwriting your imports.
- As a best practice, give your font-family rule a fallback. `font-family: 'Roboto thin', arial, sans-serif`;

Comment: - my @import was always at the top of the css file
- Tried adding the html import from the google but to no avail
- removed the font-face rules too but still didn't work.
-also added the font-family things you said but it still doesn't work. 

I am about to put the entire website in the trash bin